# Magento: Get store contact telephone

Tags: magento

Seems like it should be simple, but cant find a solution anywhere. I need to output the Store Contact Telephone number, which is in Store Informtion in the admin.

I need to output it in template files and CMS pages, what would the code be for each?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

That's a **Core configuration**, so it's saved in `core_config_data` table, and the phone information is the field:

```
general/store_information/phone
```

So, all you need is to read the configuration data as

```
$storePhone = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');
```

For CMS pages insert the following variable:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}
```

You can find more info on this [here](http://www.khemissi.com/2010/07/09/magento-diagram-website-store-store-view/), and you can always [do the reverse programmatically](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/)

Comment: Good hint. I only found that `{{config path...}}` thing works for `general/store_information/...`, but not for `general/imprint/fax` for example.

Comment: In newer Magento CE versions, these variables seem to need to be allowed for usage in static blocks. See System > Permissions > Variables