# inserting phone of paticular store in magento

Tags: magento

{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}

This method is used for inserting the phone of default store

Can anyone help me, how to insert the phone of particular store. means I have make multiple stores and want to insert phone of any one.

Comment: NB: Question is related to [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5221794/471559)

Answer (score 0):

This path is always the same and you can set the template to follow store scope instead